# how to delete in Drizzle ORM with several "where"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, drizzle

I have a function:

```
export async function deleteFavoriteTrack({profileId, trackId}) {
   await db.delete(favoriteTracks).where(eq(favoriteTracks.profileId, profileId));
}
```

I can put only one "eq".
How can i make like in prisma like:

```
where {
   profileId,
   trackId
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to delete the `favoriteTrack` where both are equal? That sounds like an `AND` is what you're after!

```js
await db.delete(favoriteTracks).where(
  and(
    eq(favoriteTracks.profileId, profileId),
    eq(favoriteTracks.trackId, trackId),
  )
)
```